# How to Add Modify Headers Value with HttpWebRequest?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I have Mozilla plug-in Modify headers, It contains header value. How can i add these values with request when i create the object of HttpWebrequest in C#.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will return all headers attached with the request : 
[HttpWebRequest.Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx)

Comment: But its returning null value while i am passing parameters in by the Modify Headers Plug-in

Answer (score 0):

You can also use header tool is more easy to use : [Header Tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/header-tool/).

Answer (score -1):

Just add your header to the Headers collection:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(headerName, value);
```

Comment: Its not my problem, I have added the header in Modify Headers, Now i wanted to get that.

Comment: You should have been more clear. Do you want to retrieve it in the server-side code?

Comment: Don't take it personal, Yes i want to retrieve it in code behind.

Comment: NP.. At the server-side you can use HttpContext.Request.Headers[headerName].. However I was testing that Mozilla plugin and noticed that it doesn't send custom headers when in closed state, so you either need to: keep it open while navigating the site or enable option "Always On:.." which is shown when you click Configuration button in the "Modify Headers" window. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You are right, I was doing that but inside the Thread class where HttpContext is null. This is the main problem. Now i got the answer. Thank you for your valuable and quick response .